# UITableViewCell Accessory Views Duplicate In Defferent Sections When Scroll The UitableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

This question make me troubled for a long time, I want to implement defferent accessory views on different cells in my tableview.

And my tableview have multiple sections, But they duplicate onto other cells in my other sections that I have not implemented when I scroll up and down the `UITableView`. I know someone said "It should be Use different identifiers when you assign `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` for each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method before,

But I don't know how to implement programmatically in detail, Anybody can write a sample code in detail help me to understand?

Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its all well and good to use different accessory views. But you have to keep in mind that if you are recycling cells, then you first try to recycle, if none available you create a cell, THEN you need to set the appropriate accessory view for the particular cell you are going to return. Who knows what the old one was for a recycled cell...